# Is it safe to execute aggregation on real time production servers?

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I need to aggregate data from a 100M rows collection spread across multiple shards. Since there are many articles showing how and why Aggregation Framework is better than Map Reduce, I've decided to go with it. The aggregation itself is very simple and it queries indexed keys, and will only be performed once. The collection must be available to the application servers at all time, including the time of the aggregation job.

Will Mongo still be responsive during the job? Of course the job will have it's impact on availability, but how much? Is it safe to start such a job on real time production environment, where the application queries the same collection frequently?

---

Additional info:

The collection has ~100M rows, each with an indexed field `groupId`. The items to by analyzed are from `groupId` G only, **and there are at most 10M items** in this group. In group G I need to group by another indexed field, say, `subGroupId`, where there are at most 90 items per sub group. An SQLish query would be:

```
select subGoupId, concat(itemId) from myCollection where groupId="x" 
    group by subGroupId 
    order by subGroupId
```

(existing indexes: {`groupId`, `subGroupId`} , {`groupId`, `itemId`})

In map reduce terms, on map stage, every mapper would emit {key: `subGroupId`, value: `itemId`}. `subGroupId`s are well distributed so there shouldn't be bottlenecked reducers. The reducers part is just to concat `itemId` values for each `subGroupId`. I would expect the map stage to load only items from `groupId` G to memory, by using {`groupId`, `subgroupId`} index, therefore only 10M items will be loaded into memory in the entire mapreduce / aggregation job.

Do these assumptions make sense?

Comment: 100M rows may be still slow with aggregation too

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of operation you'll be performing on dataset so it's hard to say anything. However, keep in mind limitations of aggregation framework. Aggregation pipeline is limited to 100MB ram or 16MB document size. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/